# Should I determine the wattage of my heater based on the heat conduction equation, or the specific heat capacity equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-conduction

I know of the equation equating rate of heat flow to the product of a materials thermal conductivity, area of contact, temperature difference, divided by the thickness of the material.

However, I also do know of the amount of energy required to heat a material up to a certain temperature, based on the amount of material used, its specific heat capacity, and the temperature difference.

I am trying to determine the wattage of a surface heater so I can heat up a flat slab of material such that the top surface of the slab is of a certain temperature.

Now here is where I face my difficulty: in order for me to choose a surface heater, should I base my choice of power rating on the energy required by the specific heat equation, divided by the time I need the material to be heated to the temperature I require?

Or should I base the wattage given by the heat conduction equation?

Terribly confused

Comment: Your first statement applies to the Fourier heat equation for steady flow through a wall. When first starting to heat the wall temperatures will be a function of both time and distance into the wall. You’ll need the general Fourier equation which is a second order differential equation involving the density and specific heat of the material as well as the thermal conductivity.